# Set variable by parsing payload using lua

Tags: nginx, lua, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

New to nginx and lua, I'm trying to set a variable by reading the request_body and then later use that variable for make changes to the proxy_pass url. Following is the conf file.

```
 # map $request_body $url {
  #   default             https://ENV_NAME.example-LANG.api.company_name.net/inference;
  #   ~*es                https://ENV_NAME.example-es.api.company_name.net/inference;;
  #   ~*fr                https://ENV_NAME.example-fr.api.company_name.net/inference;;
  # }

server {
  listen 8080;
  listen [::]:8080 ipv6only=on default_server;
  
  proxy_set_header content-type "application/json";
  client_max_body_size 100M;

  port_in_redirect off;
  proxy_ssl_server_name on;

  underscores_in_headers on;
  ignore_invalid_headers off;

  server_name translation-proxy;

  # health end-point
  location /health {
    add_header 'Content-Type' 'application/json';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
    return 200 '{"status":"Healthy"}';
  }

  location / {
    default_type application/json;
    lua_need_request_body on;
    
    resolver local=on;
    set $env_name "";
    set $lang "";
    set $url https://ENV_NAME.example-LANG.api.company_name.net/inference;
    # Exctracting environment value in env_name variable

    set_by_lua_block $env_name {
      local headers = ngx.req.get_headers()
      return headers['svc.env']
    }

    content_by_lua_block {
        local cjson = require "cjson"  
        ngx.req.read_body()
        local data = ngx.req.get_body_data()

        if data then
            local json_table = cjson.decode(data)
            local variable_value = json_table.target
            ngx.var.lang = variable_value
        else
            ngx.status = ngx.HTTP_BAD_REQUEST
            ngx.say("Bad Request: JSON payload is missing or invalid.")
            ngx.exit(ngx.HTTP_BAD_REQUEST)
        end
      }
    # set_by_lua_block $lang {
    #   ngx.req.read_body()
    #   local request_body = ngx.req.get_body_data()
    #   return request_body['source']
    # }

    set_by_lua_block $proxy_url {
      local url = string.gsub(ngx.var.url, "LANG", ngx.var.lang) 
      return string.gsub(url, "ENV_NAME", ngx.var.env_name)
    }

    proxy_pass_request_headers on;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    
    proxy_pass $proxy_url;
  }
}
```

Basically I'm trying to read the ENV from headers and LANG from payload. While ENV works fine I'm facing issue with LANG.

- Using `set_by_lua_block` (now commeted out) gives me `API disabled in the context of set_by_lua*` error or that the request_body is nil.
- Using `content_by_lua_block` doesn't throw any error but `ngx.var.lang` is empty.
- I also tried to move away from this and use map (now commented out) but I couldn't come up with a valid regex to match with the json payload.

Sample Payload:

```
{
    "utterance": "hola",
    "source": "es"
}
```

Comment: I have already gone through loads of similar questions on stackoverflow but nothing seems to work :(